# Arithmetic Mean/Geometrix Mean Inequality of Degree 3

Tags: inequality, radicals, factoring, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

For $a,b$ and $c\geq0$;
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{abc}$$

Is there a simple way to deduce this result from the degree 2 verson?

That is:
$$\frac{a+b}{2}\geq\sqrt{ab}$$

Some sort of substitution involving $a,b,c \ $ for one of the variables was what I had in mind, but I can't seem to figure it out!

Comment: [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proofs_of_the_AM.E2.80.93GM_inequality) are several proofs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This is a nice method:**

We know that $\frac{a+b}{2}\geq\sqrt{ab}$
and similarly $\frac{c+d}{2}\geq\sqrt{cd}$

so $\frac{a+b+c+d}{2}\geq\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{cd}\geq2\sqrt[4]{abcd}$

$$\Rightarrow\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}\geq\sqrt[4]{abcd}$$

and by making the substitution $d=\frac{a+b+c}{3} \rightarrow$

$$\frac{a+b+c+\frac{a+b+c}{3}}{4}\geq \sqrt[4]{ \frac{a+b+c}{3} abc }$$

$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq\sqrt[4]{ \frac{a+b+c}{3} abc }$$

Raising both sides the the power of $4$

$$(\frac{a+b+c}{3})^4\geq(\frac{a+b+c}{3})abc$$

which gives us:

$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq\sqrt[3]{abc}$$

as required.

I would love to see some more methods if you have any!

Answer (score 3):

I think, the previous method is the best (with using AM-GM for two variables),

but we can make also the following proof by the same AM-GM.

Since for non-negatives $x$, $y$ and $z$ by AM-GM we have

$\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\geq xy$ and $\frac{x^2+z^2}{2}\geq xz$ and $\frac{y^2+z^2}{2}\geq yz$,

after summing we obtain $x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz\geq0$.

Now let $a=x^3$, $b=y^3$ and $c=z^3$.

Hence, $\frac{a+b+c}{3}-\sqrt[3]{abc}=\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz}{3}=\frac{(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz)}{3}\geq0$

and we are done!

Comment: Perhaps not as 'elegant' as the other solution -- but its probably more direct and robust!!!  ( +1 )

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM (3 variables)

$\displaystyle \frac{a+b}{2}=\frac{\frac{2a}{3}+\frac{2b}3+\frac{a+b}3}{3}*\frac32\geq\frac32({\frac{2a}3*\frac{2b}3*\frac{a+b}3})^\frac13$

put
$\displaystyle \frac12({(2a)(2b)(a+b)})^\frac13-(ab)^\frac12=A-B$

$$A^6-B^6$$
$$=\displaystyle \frac{2^4}{2^6}(ab(a+b))^2-(ab)^3$$

$$=\displaystyle (ab)^2\frac14((a+b)^2-4ab)$$

$$=\displaystyle (ab)^2\frac14((a-b)^2\geq0$$

Therefore 2 variables version of AM-GM was proved.